# Server can not connect to itself through extrenal DNS

Tags: dns, domain, windows-server

I'm setting up a home infrastructure with two VMs running Windows Server 2019 :

- One with a Domain Controller, named "AD". The domain is named ad.mydomain.com
- Another one name "SSAS" with an SSAS Instance and a Power BI Report Server Instance
  Each has its own IP. I bought a domain (let's call it mydomain.com), made it point to my local network, and forwarded the 80 (http) and 2383 (SSAS) ports to the SSAS VM.

I join my personnel computer to the domain. When I connect from my computer to the SSAS instance on the "SSAS" VM, I don't have any trouble. I can connect using the server name SSAS, ssas.ad.mydomain.com, mydomain.com. Everything also works for the Power BI Report Server.

However, when I run SSMS directly on the "SSAS" VM, I can only connect to the SSAS instance using SSAS or ssas.ad.mydomain.com. When I try to use mydomain.com as the server name, I get an "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (System)" error.
I got the same issue with the Power BI Report Server : When I try to open mydomain.com on chrome, I see the authentification popup, but no matter what I input I can't connect. Therefore I think the issue may come from the link to the Domain Controller, but as everything works fine when connecting from the outside I think the link between the two VMs is ok.

On the Domain Controller DNS, I tried mapping the mydomain.com name to the "SSAS" VM's IP, but it didn't have any impact.

I can connect to the server from my personnal computer using mydomain.com when my personnel computer is connected to my lan, so I don't think it's related to a loopback blocking from the router.

This is troublesome because when I create reports, I use the mydomain.com server name, so I can't deploy them to the report server without changing the connection, making further changes harder.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Well, does the external DNS server return the same query results for `nslookup ssas.ad.mydomain.com` as the internal server? And because it looks like you're using Kerberos authentication, does it also return the same results for `nslookup <ssas_server_ip>`?

Comment: Verify that your router supports Loopback (loop to-from the Internet).